# JQuery Music Array

Tags: jquery, keycode

How can I take this first line of code and put it in a array like var sounds.

```
var audio1 = new Audio("assets/sounds/steelsword.mp3");
var sounds = Audio[
    "assets/sounds/steelsword.mp3",
    "assets/sounds/sword1.mp3",
    "assets/sounds/swordecho.mp3",
    "assets/sounds/swordraw.mp3",
    "assets/sounds/wv_sword.mp3"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sounds = [Audio("file1"), Audio("file2")]
```

Comment: for (i < 0; i<sounds.length; i++){
      var randomSound = sounds[i];
      return randomSound
    }

Comment: trying to build a for lop to return a sound to play

Comment: `var randomIndex = Math.random(0,sounds.length)`
`var randomSounds = sounds[randomIndex]`

Answer (score 1):

In raw JavaScript, you can just use **[array.push()](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=javascript%20array%20push)**:

```js
var sounds = ["assets/sounds/steelsword.mp3", "assets/sounds/sword1.mp3", "assets/sounds/swordecho.mp3", "assets/sounds/swordraw.mp3", "assets/sounds/wv_sword.mp3"];
sounds.push("assets/sounds/steelsword.mp3");
console.log(sounds);
```

Then just select the audio file that you want to load from the array, calling **[`new Audio()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)**, and setting the audio's **[`src` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_src.asp)**:

```js
var sounds = ["assets/sounds/steelsword.mp3", "assets/sounds/sword1.mp3", "assets/sounds/swordecho.mp3", "assets/sounds/swordraw.mp3", "assets/sounds/wv_sword.mp3"];
sounds.push("assets/sounds/steelsword.mp3");

var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = sounds[5];
```

Comment: Can you help me build a for loop to select a song to play?

Comment: You wouldn't be using a `for` loop for a *selection*; you would just assign `audio.src` to whatever the user picked. You could achieve that by outputting each of the options in a `<select>` element, and then calling the play functionality `onchange` of that `<select>`.